# How to make an infinite Scroll images page on HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an HTML page that i can put few images inside,
and scroll (up and down, right to left), without limits (the images will return themselves).

Here is great example for this: [MacDonalds Favourites](http://www.mcdonalds.co.uk/ukhome/promotions/favourites.html).

i've tried to do a js code that calcuate the height of the page and when he now that he came to the end of tha page - he scrolling to the top of him.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        window.scrollTo(0,0); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite scroll method does invoke jQuery, similar to what you have written here. But you would also want to bring in additional data to be displayed, which you can do in a variety of different ways.

Since you are already using jQuery, it would sense to use the .ajax() method from that library.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://your-url-here.com/extra-content.html",
}).done(function(html)  {
  $("#results").append(html); 
});
```

See the jQuery docs for more information on the .ajax method:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try using iscroll with infinite scrolling
i will recommend that you also use snap to element for images to give it a carousel look
http://iscrolljs.com/#infinite-scrolling